# JHipster: Create an entity and move it to admin

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

I created an entity with yo `jhipster:entity MyEntity` and everything works fine. But this entity should be part of the admin section so I moved the whole folder and updated the paths etc.

But now the whole app can not load any more. It says:

```
"Invalid configuration of route '': Encountered undefined route.
  The reason might be an extra comma."
```

I just copied myEntityRoute to ADMIN_ROUTES. How can I figure out the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Please list out the configuration in your admin/index.ts. You need to export your new entity configuration before "export * from './admin.route';"

Comment: Could you point to where in the documentation is specified that the order of exports matter? It works, thank you very much!